# Trouble with positioning footer

Tags: html, css

So, for a long time I thought my footer was working properly (sitting at the bottom of the page), but when I slide down and there's content that goes under the footer, something like this happens https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljEqc.jpg

It sits where it was and doesn't want to go down. Basically the footer doesn't go down as wrapper expands. I tried approching this a  few times, for example applying overflow: hidden to wrapper, placing footer outside the wrapper, trying to set it with margin, but none of these options helped. Honestly, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
Code that might help (I deleted colours etc to make it more clear)
.footer{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
body{
    margin: 0px !important;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Wrapper is around all my code (starting before nav and ending after footer). Also- placing footer not in wrapper helped, but then it isn't visible after loading the page- I have to slide down to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so trivial I found myself embarassed- putting margin-bottom on wrapper helped.